# How to send server side CSS and JS to client side in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new at MVC application development.I'm working on Visual studio ASP.NET MVC4 project. I want to send my server-side CSS and JS to the client side in a .cshtml file. How the work will be done. Is it right way of doing this?

Comment: can you post some example of what you have tried or what your chtml looks like right now?

Comment: What are you doing with the CSS and JS that you're sending back to the client?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Controller method:

```
    public ActionResult GetCss()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        return View("Css1", new FontSpec {FontName = "Arial"});
    }
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.FontSpec

.foo
{
    font-family: @Model.FontName;
}
```

Simplified Model:

```
public class FontSpec
{
    public string FontName {get; set;}
}
```

The important part is to set the ContentType in the controller method.  The model can be used to pass dynamically generated data to your view, making your CSS truly dynamic.

In your page view (the view that actually generates the page) you can use the following link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@(Url.Action("GetCss", "Home"))"/>
```

And finally, of course, you can use your CSS classes in your tags:

```
<span class="foo">This will be in your specified font.</span>
```

You can, of course, generate your CSS by any means you like, as long as it is legal CSS at the end of the processing.  This will also work for generating dynamic Javascript, but of course you have to change the content type you use.